# Eclipse Perspective won't stop resetting

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, perspective

I want to have the Debug actions in my toolbar. But every time I exit eclipse and open it again it disappears. I always have to go to `Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective > Action Bar Availability` and rechecking the Debug box and I'm sick of doing this.

Also when I debug my program and hit a breakpoint, I get this pop-up `'Perspective Switch Job' has encountered a problem.` With the details being `Error java.lang.NullPointerException`. Sometimes when this pop-up comes up the Debug actions on my toolbar disappear and have to follow the instructions above to get it back.

I have tried saving a perspective the the Debug toolbar and making it my default perspective but it hasn't been working, I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or not.

I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: Mars Release (4.5.0). I am using Pydev with it, my code is near exclusively python. I have not been developing Java on this machine.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-01-25 09:40:26.700
!MESSAGE Error
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyShowView(WorkbenchPage.java:1270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$12.run(WorkbenchPage.java:4211)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:4207)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.views.ViewContextService.showViewQuiet(ViewContextService.java:1175)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.PerspectiveManager$4.runInUIThread(PerspectiveManager.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.PerspectiveManager$MyUIJob$1.run(PerspectiveManager.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message about the 'perspective switch job' error.

Comment: I added the log message of the error